# Python: Iterate with a list inside a function

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to use elements from a list inside a for cycle, trying to reproduce the making of the Fibonacci series in music, generating sinewave in Python.
The function to generate the sine.

```
def genSine(A, f, phi, fs, t):
    """
    A=amplitude of sin
    f=frequency
    phi = initial phase in rad
    fs= sampl freq
    t= duration
    """
    time = np.arange(0, t, 1.0/fs)
    Y = A * np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * time + phi)
    return Y
```

Those are the list

fibonacciDigit is the fibonacciSeries but with a single number, using that to call the notes
ex: 0 = 311 / 1 = 329 / 2 = 369 / ecc...

```
    fibonacciDigit = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x 
          for z in fibonacciSeries for x in str(z)]
print(fibonacciDigit)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 8, 9, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 3, 7, 7]
```

List of frequencies/notes
notes = [311, 329, 369, 415, 440, 493, 554, 622, 659, 739]
fibonacciNotes = [notes[i] for i in fibonacciDigit]
That is the function to generate the sine from the Fibonacci sequence.

```
def fibonacciSines(myArray):
 for i in range(len(myArray)):
    xFreq = [x for x in myArray]
    freqFibonacci = genSine(0.2,xFreq,0,44100,1)
```

I'm not so sure which way is the best to obtain the result.
I'm using a for loop connected to the number of element, so I'll have a new list with exact same number of element for every note, now I need to pass the information xFreq to the for cycle, hoping to have a new list made of sine elements, this is the "not so sure" part: maybe

The code is curretly not working. One of the problem is that I'm passing an array to a function who accept only float value.
I need a cycle because i want the fuction to be done as many times as the value in myArray.
I'm expecting to receive multiple arrays, then to concatenate them into only one.

What I expect from that function is that on every for cycle xFreq is equal to a value taken from myArray (in my example is a list of frequencies corresponding to fibonacciNotes), so that I will have multiple sine arrays generated with different freq taken.

```
print(fibonacciNotes)
[311, 329, 329, 369, 415, 493, 659, 329, 415, 369, 329, 415, 440, 493, 493, 659, 739, 329, 440, 440, 369, 415, 415, 415, 622, 622]
```

A generic example of the sine generator

```
# GENERIC SINE GENERATOR
Z = genSine(0.5,1500,1,44100,2)
Y = genSine(0.2,440,1,44100,2)
X = np.concatenate((Z, Y))
print(X)
[0.42073549 0.46846029 0.49487015 ... 0.14512357 0.15346013 0.1611938 ]
```

Comment: You're going to have to try to make this post clearer. It's not clear what result you want, and the code has many unexplained things. What is `fibonacciDigit`? Where are you using `fibonacciNotes`? Why doesn't `fibonacciSines` return anything? `xFreq` is a list, but you're passing it into a function `genSine` that multiplies it by a `float` `np.pi`.

Comment: Does your code currently work at all? What output do you want, and what do you currently get?

Comment: share some sample i/o, so that we can help you to find a solution

Comment: instead of `xFreq = [x for x in myArray]` you can use `xFreq = myArray` or `xFreq = myArray.copy()` if you have to duplicate it.

Comment: I don't understand your question. I don't understand why you even use this `for`-loop. WHy not send `myArray` directly to `genSine` without `for`-loop.

Comment: and what do you have in `fibonacciDigit`? And you create `fibonacciNotes` but never us it.

Comment: I've added new information to the question, thank you all for your answers.

Comment: Do you want your output to concatenate the result of `genSine` for the list of frequencies `[311, 329, 329, 369, 415, 493, 659, 329, 415, 369, 329, 415,...` ? Into a single long array? If so, you could use `output = np.concatenate([genSine(0.2, f, 0, 44100, 1) for f in fibonacciNotes])`